# Как получить автоматически значение бекенда в nginx (например из listen)?

Tags: сервер, nginx, веб-сервер

Есть сотни сайтов, проксирует их nginx. В каждой секции server подключен файл, дабы была возможность быстро прописывать конфиги для всех сразу.

До сей поры прописывал различные условия, всё было хорошо, пока не наткнулся на location и proxy_pass.

Дело в том, что proxy_pass требует прописать бекенд. В моем случае для сотен сайтов прописаны разные бекенды в виде IP-адресов. Эти IP, например, совпадают с listen в секции server. Если значение proxy_pass не совпадает с listen, то выдает 404 для указанного location.

Каким образом можно автоматически определить backend, соответствующий сайту? Может быть, как-то из listen значение IP можно вытащить?

Вот код, который инклудится к каждому сайту:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php|admin|administrator) {
                        limit_req  zone=wp burst=4 nodelay;
                        proxy_pass http://IP:81;
                        proxy_redirect http://IP/ /;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Значение скопировать никак нельзя – генерите этот конфиг файл скриптом каким-нибудь.

Общие для всех `server` строки конфигов можно вынести в один отдельный файл `common_proxy.conf`:

#### site_N.conf:

```
listen 123.123.123.123:80;
...
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php|admin|administrator) {
  proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123;
  proxy_redirect http://IP/ /;
  include common_proxy.conf
}
```

#### common_proxy.conf:

```
limit_req  zone=wp burst=4 nodelay;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Comment: значение proxy_pass придется опять каким-то образом определить... или я Вас не понял... скрипт конечно можно попробовать сделать, но пока хотелось бы без этого поискать решение проблемы

Comment: `proxy_pass` придётся прописывать в конфиге каждого сервера – там же, где и `listen`. Но сохраняется возможность разом всем поменять, скажем, `limit_req` – он один для всех из одного общего файла.  Но IP адрес придётся прописывать дважды. Я не нашёл [переменных nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), подходящих для желаемого вами решения.

Comment: @Sergiks, протестировал, у меня работает объявление переменной в секции server, с использованием её значения в подключаемом файле. см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

проверил на *nginx* версии `1.4.6`.

создал две секции `server`, слушающие разные ip-адреса:

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8001;
  set $pp "127.0.0.1";
  include test.conf;
}
server {
  listen 127.0.0.2:8001;
  set $pp "127.0.0.2";
  include test.conf;
}
```

содержимое `test.conf`:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://$pp:9001;
}
```

в двух отдельных экземлярах оболочки запустил процессы, слушающие нужные ip-адреса и порты:

1. `$ nc -l 127.0.0.1 9001`
2. `$ nc -l 127.0.0.2 9001`

перезапустил *nginx*, сделал два запроса (т.к. я не задал таймаута, пришлось «убивать» их нажатием <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>):

1. `$ wget -qO - http://127.0.0.1:8001/`
2. `$ wget -qO - http://127.0.0.2:8001/`

процессы *nc* показали ожидаемую информацию:

1. тот, который слушал адрес `127.0.0.1`:

   ```
   GET / HTTP/1.0
   Host: 127.0.0.1:9001
   Connection: close
   User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)
   Accept: */*
   ```
2. тот, который слушал адрес `127.0.0.2`:

   ```
   GET / HTTP/1.0
   Host: 127.0.0.2:9001
   Connection: close
   User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)
   Accept: */*
   ```

### то есть, вполне можно использовать примерно следующее:

1. в секции `server` присваивать нужное значение какой-нибудь переменной. если это не число, а строка, например, ip-адрес, его следует заключить в кавычки. например:

   ```
   set $some_var = "1.2.3.4";
   ```
2. во включаемом файле подставить имя этой переменной в требующемся месте. например:

   ```
   proxy_pass http://$some_var:81;
   ```

---

а какой-либо внутренней переменной, содержащей адрес, по которому произошёл запрос, в [документации](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) *nginx-а*, увы, нет.

Comment: Тоже придётся в каждом конфиге дважды прописывать IP адрес: в `listen` и назначая его переменной (у меня 2-й раз непосредственно в директиве `proxy_pass`). Лучше генерить конфиг-файлы каким-то скриптом. Я бы так поступил. P.s. +1 за детальное изучение вопроса и эксперимент. p.p.s. nginx пора обновить.

Comment: 1. один раз: `set v="1.2.3.4"; listen $v:81;` (исправил ответ) 2. обновлять не требуется. эта машина выполняет совсем другие задачи, а nginx исключительно для (моих) тестов стоит.

Comment: @Sergiks, откатил пока правку, т.к. `listen` почему-то не захотел переменную принимать. потестирую ещё.

Comment: @Sergiks, в директиве listen переменные воспринимать не хочет. да, согласен, тогда придётся ip-адрес упоминать дважды.