# Массово защитить сайты от перебора?

Tags: nginx, защита, iptables, взлом, брутфорс

Приветствую... может быть у кого был опыт защиты админок от массового перебора? На сервере сотни сайтов. Имеется защита по количеству соединений, но боты теперь стали умнее - делают лишь небольшое количество запросов в минуту, что практически незаметно, при этом создавая излишнюю, неприятную нагрузку на процессор.

```
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:36:55 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 2769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:04 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5021 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:09 +0300] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:09 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4488 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:10 +0300] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3316 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:11 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4307 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:12 +0300] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 2769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:12 +0300] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 2769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
46.172.83.5 - - [28/Jun/2016:11:37:12 +0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 403 2769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0" "-"
```

Что делать с ними? Может быть поделитесь своим опытом?..

Пытался сделать при помощи nginx, но проблема [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539284/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-nginx-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7-listen)...

Answer (score 2):

[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) может помочь. Это инструмент, который автоматически банит в iptables узлы, подозреваемые в зловредной активности, исходя из анализа логов. Бан может быть постоянным или временным – fail2ban может и разбанивать их через какое-то время. Гибкие настройки, «все пользуются».

Для анализа попыток входа в WordPress надо будет установить [этот плагин WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fail2ban/), чтобы попытки заходов записывались в syslog. [Подробнее тут](https://bjornjohansen.no/using-fail2ban-with-wordpress) (на англ.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос заключался в "массовости". Если исходить из Вашего ответа, мне придется устанавливать на сотни сайтов плагин для WP, что нереально...

Comment: @АлексейСекретный можно и без плагина, fail2ban может работать и банить сам по себе, тоже рекомендую

Comment: @andreymal есть примеры конфигов?

Comment: @АлексейСекретный с собой нету, но в гугле про вордпресс должно быть навалом, и с самим fail2ban тоже примеры для разных ситуаций есть

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте адрес для логина с /wp-login.php на ещё что-то . 95% ботов отсеятся. Они весьма тупые, в них просто записано - где логин у вордпресса. Сделайте так - чтобы не знали :)

Comment: думаете простой rewrite поможет?

Comment: необходимо, чтобы по старому адресу  /wp-login.php  - логин произвести было нельзя. Так что нет - не по может. Нужно в коде заменить ссылки на wp-login.php. В вордпрессе наверняка есть такая опция. А затем уже можно и реврайт - только чтобы старый адрес не работал.

Comment: ну в загаловке же написано, что должна быть массовость, я не могу ведь у каждого сайта менять код :(

Comment: Тогда извините, помочь не могу. Но знаю чтоесть серверные утилиты которые могут пристально относиться к запросом на определённые URL .